# How can you create still image fire in Blender 2.8 Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, fire

I'm working on an interior scene of an old witch's house that will have a fire in a hearth.  It is just a still image and will not have any animation.  What are some ways of modeling a fire for a scene like this with no animation?  I'm working in Blender 2.82 Cycles.  Thanks to any replies.

Comment: what style are you looking for? realistic? cartoony? maybe show some pictures... you could simply model it with some face extrusions, or create a plane and use some procedural texture, etc...

Comment: I'm aiming for a more realistic look.  Nothing low poly or a similar style.

Comment: so maybe use a photo, create a transparent background in an image editor software, and use it as an image texture on a plane?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning to create fire in Blender as well but what helped me was (if you're down with that?) is using premade FireFX mov. files and import them as planes. They are ofc animated but you can use it as stills also and it's a great way to use fire in your art even though you did not make them yourself atm. You should be able to shape it in a heart in some way. When you import them make sure to select EMIT or the fire won't be bright. Also it will shine on objects in Cycles but you have to add a light in Evee to create the illusion. Grts
PS; I've used these; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pljzKVwkzU
Link is in the description below the video. Hope this helped a bit. I for one can't get Mantaflow to work for the life of me no matter how much tutorials I copy to the letter so this helped me out seriously. Happy creating!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple plane. You can find plenty of images of fire online/ Look for the ones with black background to make things easier. Then you can just have a Transparent shader and add an Emission shader to it ant that's it.

[image]

Hide it in a fireplace, add some fire wood and some interior around it and it's all good:

[image]

Comment: I see now, I am a few years too late. :D I thought this was a new question.